# IE, overflow and the disappearing list items

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Greetings Friends,

I need some help! I've built an address finder where you enter a postcode then the "Find Address" button triggers a modal window. This modal window then takes the given postcode and loads in the appropriate data...

The troubles begin when you try to expand the address list: the list expands then disappears in IE8. It works in FF.

A working example is at: http://www.equanet.co.uk/apply
Try using postcode: **M24 2NN**

**The HTML for the generated content is:**

```
<div class="addressFinder" style="position: fixed; top: 251px; left: 252px;">
  <h5><input id="closeBut" value="X" type="button"> Address finder</h5>
  <ul class="addresslist">
    <li class="area priv open"><span>Hereford Way, Middleton, MANCHESTER, Lancashire, M24 2NN</span>
      <ul style="display: block;" class="addresses">
        <li class="address" index="0" id="addr_0">< span>47</span></li>
        <li class="address" index="1" id="addr_1"><span>49</span></li>
        <li class="address" index="2" id="addr_2"><span>51</span></li>
        <li class="address" index="3" id="addr_3"><span>53</span></li>
        <li class="address" index="4" id="addr_4"><span>54</span></li>
        <li class="address" index="5" id="addr_5"><span>55</span></li>
        and so on...
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="area org"><span>Hereford Way, Middleton, MANCHESTER, Lancashire, M24 2NN</span>
      <ul style="display: none;" class="addresses">
        <li class="address" index="49" id="addr_49"><span>Bellinso, 98</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**The CSS is:**

```
.addressFinder { position: absolute; z-index: 999; display: block; width: 60%; padding: 0.5em; margin: 0; background: #DDD; text-align: left; }
.addressFinder h5 { margin: 0; font-size: 1.25em; line-height: 2; }
.addressFinder ul { list-style: none; marging: 0; padding: 0; }
.addressFinder ul.addresslist { height: 20em !important; clear: both; overflow-y: scroll; margin: 0; background: #EEE; }
.addressFinder ul.addresslist ul { height: auto; margin: 0 0 0 1em; padding: 0; }

.addressFinder .addresslist span { display: block; cursor: pointer; line-height: 1.5; }
.addressFinder .addresslist span:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
.addressFinder #closeBut { float: right; margin-top: 0.2em; }
.addressFinder .priv, .addressFinder .priv li { list-style-image: url(/ui/icons/house.png); }
.addressFinder .org { list-style-image: url(/ui/icons/building.png); }
.addressFinder .priv li { list-style: none; }
```

I'm unsure if it's a problem with my CSS or if I'm falling victim to a geniune browser bug.

Comment: Works fine in IE8. Do you mean IE7, or IE8's [IE7] Compatibility Mode? It doesn't work there.

Comment: I'm using IE8. When I click to expanding either the Private or Organisation lists their respective content disappears. When the content expands the vertical scrollbar becomes active but does not seem to move the list in any direction. I am using the address finder in several different locations; one page uses <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /> in the <head> and the other doesn't. It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, it works fine in my IE8. I'm assuming here you've somehow got your IE8 in IE7 mode, where the problem you describe occurs.

Remove `position: relative` from the `li` tags inside `<ul class="addresslist">`.

You have in your `core.css`:

```
li { position: relative; /* For IE list white-space bug */ padding-left: 0.25em; }
```

Remove that, just to test. If that resolves your problem, then:

- Please provide a reference link to the named "IE list white-space bug", so I can suggest what to do next (for example, what versions of IE does the named bug occur in?).

Alternatively, you can keep the above line, and just add this to your CSS:

```
li.area, li.address { position: static } /* to fix IE7 */
```

This will *"remove"* `position: relative` from just the afflicted `<li>` tags.

Comment: Brilliant! The lists no longer disappear. Thank you. But it seems that the scrollbar doesn't move the list as intended, the list-items are now frozen in place.

Comment: I see. It's still `li { position: relative }` biting you in the ass. You also need to remove `position: relative` from `<li class="address">`. You can do it in a similar way to before. See my updated answer.

Comment: Sir, thank you for rescuing me! I've been such a thickie today. Lessons have been learned. Go have yourself a well-deserved drink of something awesome...